# how can i create textbox which can save any input in database using jquery ajax in Asp.net mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

How do I create textbox which can save any input in database using jquery Ajax in Asp.net mvc4...
e.g:I write "my new task" in textbox and click on button and this saves in database with "The project" id and the "UserId" which is login in application,
so how can I create this in mvc4, here is my code..

```
public actionresult Insert(task,projectId,UserId)
{
    //linq to sql here...
}
```

and Ajax code is

```
source: function(request, response) {

                 $.ajax({
                 url: pagePath + "/insert",
                     data: "{ 'id': '" + request.term + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                     success: function(data) {

                         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                             {
                                 value = item.Name 
                                 return value;
                             }
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, callStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert(callStatus);
                     }
                 });
             },
```

Is this the correct way? Can someone please guide me

Comment: are you getting an error when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
source: function(request, response) {

                 $.ajax({
                 url: "controllername/actionmethodname",
                     data: "{task:value,projectId:value,UserId:value }",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     success: function(data) {

                         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                             {
                                 value = item.Name 
                                 return value;
                             }
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, callStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert(callStatus);
                     }
                 });
             },
```